# Returning Struct Array in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

This is my contract code. Here I'm trying to store the coordinates of a particular trip. While storing the information contract executing fine. But When I retrieve the data, It should give the array of coordinates. But it is throwing an error.

> reason: 'insufficient data for uint256 type'

```
contract TripHistory {
       struct Trip {
           string lat;
           string lon;
       }
        mapping(string => Trip[]) trips;

        function getTrip(string _trip_id) public view returns (Trip[]) {
            return trips[_trip_id];
        }
        function storeTrip(string _trip_id, string _lat, string _lon) public  {
           trips[_trip_id].push(Trip(_lat, _lon));
        }

}
```

What I'm missing here. Is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying here?

P.S: I'm new to solidity.

Answer (score 6):

First of returning structs is not supported in Solidity directly. Instead you need to return every individual element in the struct as below.

```
Function xyz(uint256 _value) returns(uint256 User.x, uint256 User.y)
public {}
```

But then there’s an experimental feature that will help you with returning struct. All that you need to do is add the following after your first pragma line

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

then continue with your code. That should work with no changes to your code.

An example of abiencoderv2 returning struct can be found at this [link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/abi-spec.html?highlight=abiencoderv2)

Comment: Where can I find list of features supported by `ABIEncoderV2`?

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to the reference implementation of abiencoderv2

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in solidity to return struct array.

Comment: is this still true?

Comment: I can with solidity 5.16 an the ABIEncoderV2

Answer (score 0):

As **jlo** said in this [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/101745), after version 0.8.0, it is possible to return a struct. **jlo** describes how to set and return **an element of array of struct**. Here I describe how to set, reset, and return a **struct type variable**.

I tested it and my test environment is:

1. private Ethereum network
2. Geth version 1.10.9-stable (for private network)
3. Slocjs Compiler version 0.8.7
4. web3js version 1.5.1

Note, you have to first define the **struct type** outside of any function inside the contract.

A supper intuitive example code is as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
contract testContract {


    struct funcResultType {
        uint[] var1;
        string[] var2;
        string message;
    }

    funcResultType private funcResult;


    function testSetFunc(string memory inputVar) public payable {
        funcResult.var1.push(123);
        funcResult.var2.push(inputVar);
        funcResult.message = "Done!";
    }

    function testResetFunc() public payable {
        delete funcResult; // reset variales
    }

    function testGetFunc() public view returns (funcResultType memory){
        return funcResult;
    }
}
```

The result of the test with Web3js in the console is as follow:

[image]

As you can see the whole variables are accessible. I upload its web3js code in Github in this [link](https://github.com/javaditco/Learning-by-example-1-Web3js-return-struct).